# Escape variables to go into script

Tags: bash, scripting

In Bash, I've been trying to get the following content into a file:

```
for pid in $(ps -lef | grep ssh | grep 2048 | awk '{print $4}'); do kill -9 $pid; done
```

Doesn't matter how I try to put it, in, say, FileA, it always ends up having the variables substituted by the real values. I've EOF and echo. No luck.

My end goal is to have FileA with the content of the one-liner.

Comment: What is `2048`? A port number, PID, PPID, or some command line value? What is your pipeline trying to do? It would be safer with `pkill -f ssh -p 2048`.  Note that your command would match any `sshd` server that happens to run with a PID or PPID _containing_ the substring `2048`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say "I've EOF" I imagine you mean you tried a [here document](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Documents), but have you tried quoting the heredoc *word*?

```
cat <<'EOF' >FileA
for pid in $(ps -lef | grep ssh | grep 2048 | awk '{print $4}'); do kill -9 $pid; done
EOF
```

> If word is unquoted, all lines of the here-document are subjected to parameter expansion, command substitution, and arithmetic expansion, the character sequence \newline is ignored, and ‘\’ must be used to quote the characters ‘\’, ‘$’, and ‘`’.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you you so much!